# which one of the following is true ? ...

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

My attempts : my answer is option $(C)$

sup{$a_n | n \in R  $}= $2  +  0 = 2$ where $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}=\frac {(-1)}{n}=0$

and inf {$a_n |n \in  N$} = $1 + 0 $   where  $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \frac {1}{2^n}=0$

Is my answer is correct /incorrect ??

Any hints /solution will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should not confuse convergence with sup

Comment: Computing the first values of $a_n$ should prevent you from believing the supremum is $2$.